# Is it possible to get this to work

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to get this to work together. It is two different pieced of count down clocks. I am very new to javascript and am just getting php down. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I tried the best I could. The best i got was the 4 blue blocks to show up but the numbers and days did not show up in them. Thank You for your time.

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("June 5, 2018 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    
    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
    // Output the result in an element with id="clockdiv"
    document.getElementById("clockdiv").innerHTML = days + "days " + hours + "h "
    + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    
    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("clockdiv").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
}, 1000);
```

```css
#clockdiv {
color: #ffffff;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 100;
text-align: center;
}

#clockdiv > div {
background: #0294cb;
border-radius: 3px;
display: inline-block;
padding: 8px;
}

#clockdiv div > span {
background: #42baff;
border-radius: 3px;
display: inline-block;
padding: 15px;
}

.smalltext {
font-size: 14px;
padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="clockdiv">
<div>
<span class="days"></span>
<div class="smalltext">Days</div>
</div>
<div>
<span class="hours"></span>
<div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
</div>
<div>
<span class="minutes"></span>
<div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
</div>
<div>
<span class="seconds"></span>
<div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script works, but it replaces on an update the content of `#clockdiv` with plain text. And because of `color: #ffffff;` in your css you cannot see this text.

I fixed your script for you:

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("June 5, 2018 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    
    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
    // Output the result in an element with id="clockdiv"
    document.getElementsByClassName("days")[0].innerHTML = days;
    document.getElementsByClassName("hours")[0].innerHTML = hours;
    document.getElementsByClassName("minutes")[0].innerHTML = minutes;
    document.getElementsByClassName("seconds")[0].innerHTML = seconds;
    
    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("clockdiv").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
}, 1000);
```

```css
#clockdiv {
color: #ffffff;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 100;
text-align: center;
}

#clockdiv > div {
background: #0294cb;
border-radius: 3px;
display: inline-block;
padding: 8px;
}

#clockdiv div > span {
background: #42baff;
border-radius: 3px;
display: inline-block;
padding: 15px;
}

.smalltext {
font-size: 14px;
padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="clockdiv">
<div>
<span class="days"></span>
<div class="smalltext">Days</div>
</div>
<div>
<span class="hours"></span>
<div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
</div>
<div>
<span class="minutes"></span>
<div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
</div>
<div>
<span class="seconds"></span>
<div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can not thank you enough for this. I tried for the last 7 hours to fix it. Again thank you very much that was greatly appreciated.

Comment: @peeknuckle If the answer helped you, you can [vote or accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).